# Correlation of Global Stratospheric AOD with Global Mean Temperature Anomaly

Tags: climate-change, climate, aerosol

I'm trying to understand at a high level the relationship of aerosols to the global temperature and I'm new to these concepts.

I have Stratoshperic mean global AOD data from:
https://data.giss.nasa.gov/modelforce/strataer/tau.line_2012.12.txt

Global temperature anomaly from here:
https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/graphs/graph_data/Global_Mean_Estimates_based_on_Land_and_Ocean_Data/graph.txt

This is the scatterplot for the non-smoothed global mean temperature anomaly and AOD:

[image: Annual Mean Temperature]
[image: Global AOD]

My understanding is that the Aerosols decreases the temperature and it has short term effects. So the negative sign seems ok to me but is the magnitude here makes sense? i.e. the Aerosol has a weak relationship with the global temperature?

```
      Temp       aod
Temp  1.0       -0.113206
aod  -0.113206   1.000000
```